# Different result in datepart using variable vs varchar

Tags: sql-server

This query:

```
SET datefirst 7
DECLARE @data datetime = '2020-01-03 00:00:00.000'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @data)
```

Returns `1` (which is correct)

However, this query:

```
SET datefirst 7

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '2020-01-03 00:00:00.000')
```

Returns `2` which is not correct.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unambiguous format for your data and you get a consistent result. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm` is not unambiguous in SQL Server, only `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)` and `yyyyMMdd` are regardless of data type and language.

The below returns 1 for both:

```
set datefirst 7
DECLARE @data datetime = '2020-01-03T00:00:00.000'

select DATEPART(week,@data)
GO

set datefirst 7
select DATEPART(week,'2020-01-03T00:00:00.000')
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5533ac25a1952435e7bd81d5d937508)